# Hotkey of Erase in Texture Paint?

Tags: texture-painting

I found my Wacom eraser could work on Texture Paint.
so maybe there is a shortcut assigning to it?
but I cannot find it in preference

Answer (score 3):

I don't use the eraser on my tablet(mine doesn't come with one) but Texture Paint mode has a mix mode in the brush controls called 'Erase Alpha', and that generally does what you expect in that it seems to erase the paint - BUT if you also then switch to 'Add Alpha', you can then recover what you thought was erased.

I don't know about setting up an operator to swap to the Erase Alpha mix mode and back to the last used brush mix mode, but that might be possible, and then you woudl have to map it to the eraser input. I use an add-on called EZ Paint that enables me to toggle erase/add alpha with a short cut key, but that isn't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i finally figured out how to make a shortcut to an eraser for Texture Paint.

The idea is that i needed to figure out the correct function id for the Blend modes (MIX + Erase-Alpha) and input that into the custom keymap menu

But usually when using digital art softwares for drawing you can have an eraser key that will erase only when pressed.
So i made 2 diferent keymaps one change to Erase-Alpha when PRESED and the other to switch back to Mix when Released.
This basically restore my workflow and avoid so much frustration while Texture painting.

Go in the preferences - > Keymaps -> 3d View -> Image Paint
Go on the bottom and create a new key slot by pressing : Add New then click on the little arrow next to none to open the tab of the shortcut

Then in the field where its written "none" type :

wm.context_toggle_enum

new fields will appear, in Context Attribute, type :

tool_settings.image_paint.brush.blend

in the first "Value" field, type :

ERASE_ALPHA

and in the second, type :

MIX

Now set a key for your shortcut and set the key mode to : PRESS

Repeat the whole operation a second type (create another keymap in the same place) but this time, revert the 2 Values
first :
MIX
second :
ERASE_ALPHA

set the same key as before, but this time set it to RELEASE

that way you will be able to erase only while holding the eraser key, but you can also simply make only one keymap and click it to switch between modes.

Hope it Helps !

[image: Example]

Comment: THANK YOU for the basis
You actually don't need the second one, pressing the hotkey twice will toggle from one mode to another

Comment: Yeah, my setup was meant to be able to erase only when i kept the erase key pressed then automatically switching back when released. but after some testing, this is probably not a good approach, and you should make a toggle key.